# Enum.IsDefined with flagged enums

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums, flags

I'm currently reading the book [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959), which by the way I think is an excellent book, even for advanced programmers to use as a good reference.

I was looking back on the chapters about the basics, and I came across a trick to tell if a certain value is defined in an Enum when using flagged enums.
The book states that using `Enum.IsDefined` doesn't work on flagged enums, and suggests a work-around like this :

```
static bool IsFlagDefined(Enum e)
{
    decimal d;
    return (!decimal.TryParse(e.ToString(), out d);
}
```

This should return true if a certain value is defined in an enum which is flagged.

Can someone please explain to me why this works ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: as an aside theres another case where Enum.IsDefined might behave different from expected (or maybe that's default(T)). Enum.IsDefined(default(T)) can return both true and _false_. default(T) (where T is an enum) always returns (T)0 so if T does not have a valid value for (T)0 the result is false. Have trhown me off at least once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, calling `ToString` on any `enum` value of a type declared with the `[Flags]` attribute will return something like this for any defined value:

```
SomeValue, SomeOtherValue
```

On the other hand, if the value is *not* defined within the `enum` type, then `ToString` will simply produce a string representation of that value's *integer* value, e.g.:

```
5
```

So what this means is that if you can parse the output of `ToString` as a number (not sure why the author chose `decimal`), it isn't defined within the type.

Here's an illustration:

```
[Flags]
enum SomeEnum
{
    SomeValue = 1,
    SomeOtherValue = 2,
    SomeFinalValue = 4
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is defined.
        SomeEnum x = SomeEnum.SomeOtherValue | SomeEnum.SomeFinalValue;

        Console.WriteLine(x);

        // This is not (no bitwise combination of 1, 2, and 4 will produce 8).
        x = (SomeEnum)8;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
SomeOtherValue, SomeFinalValue
8
```

So you can see how the suggested method works.

Comment: Should SomeEnum.SomeValue = 0?

Comment: @PaulB: It can be. Are you asking because typically there is a `None` value for 0? That is true and probably less confusing. Maybe I'll update the answer just so as not to throw anyone off.

Comment: Yes - just that you couldn't represent SomeValue with any of the others... Thanks for changing :)

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `e` isn't can't be created using a combination of flags `ToString()` defaults to an integral number. And integral numbers will of course parse as `decimal`.

But why your code parses as decimal isn't entirely clear to me. But probably integral types won't work for both `enum`s that are based in `Int64` and `UInt64`.